# Bash: use parameters of function to do a grep search

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to create a function that will take the parameters that I pass it and do a grep search in my current directory, but I can't figure out how to use all the parameters as one string.

Here is what I have:

```
search()
{
  clear
  grep -rnw . -e $("\"" $@ "\"")
}
```

So if I were to type, `search title =`, I would want it to do `grep -rnw . -e "title ="`

Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: how do would I make it so I can use other characters without quotes? such as > or " or other escape characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"$*"` if you want all passed arguments as a single string:

```
search() {
  clear
  grep -rnw "$*" .
}
```